# Using JS to build a notification card that disappears after X seconds but the timer resets on hover

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout, dom-events

I'm using React to build a component that will act as a notification card when a user completes an action. The behavior will be like so:

When a user creates a post on a forum, the card will appear at the bottom, fixed. If the user doesn't hover over it for 4 seconds, it will disappear. If they hover over it, the timer will reset and the moment the mouse leaves the card, the timer will count down from 4 again.

Here is my relevant code for the logic:

```
let elem = document.getQuerySelector('card');

let loop = (el) => {
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        hide();
    }, duration);

    el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => { 
            // let elClone = el.cloneNode(true);
            // el.parentNode.replaceChild(elClone, el);
            loop(el);
        });
    });

}

loop(elem)
```

This code works but it ends up attaching an unnecessary amount of redundant eventListeners to the element. I tried removing all the event listeners after mouseout by cloning and replacing the element but that didn't work for me; instead the card would not disappear at all if I used this method.

Comment: Perhaps using state could give you more options of achieving this. If someone else doesn't answer this, I will give this a shot and post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using `mouseenter` and `mouseout` so only once adding the listener will work.

```
let elem = document.querySelector('card');

let loop = (el) => {
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        hide();
    }, duration);

    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => { 
        // let elClone = el.cloneNode(true);
        // el.parentNode.replaceChild(elClone, el);
        timer = setTimeout(()=>{hide()}, duration);
    });
}

loop(elem)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to do this with React, I think they have alternatives to settings eventlisteners. Could be wrong though.

Comment: I have edited the code a bit so it will not call the loop recursively, whatever i have coded though not related to React, its on basic of logic and avoid multiple event listener registering

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I didn't even think about using state @DanielZuzevich but that would have worked too. I think this answer is a lot simpler though.